# Looking for Scala or Java library that supports symbolic algebra and step-by-step symbolic solutions

Tags: library, java, scala, symbolic-algebra

I'm looking for a library in (preferably) Scala or Java that supports symbolic algebra (solving equations in an algebraic way, not just numerically).  It would also be really great if it supported step-by-step solutions, though not strictly necessary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Symja](https://github.com/axkr/symja_android_library) - Java computer algebra and symbolic math library.
In this github repository you can find some (older) [symja_scala_examples](https://github.com/axkr/symja_scala_examples) how to call it from Scala